# Group dataset two ways in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a large dataset that I need to group in two different ways. My hope is that I will be able to run a query once, so that I won't have to run two separate queries.

I guess this might be possible using `ROLLUP` or `GROUPING SETS`, but I must admit I do not fully understand how I can use them for this.

This is a basic example of what I'm trying to do. The two questions I'm trying to answer with one query is:

- How many users have been created per company per day?
- Which companies has created the most users during the entire period? Top 5 companies would be enough.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_users (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    companyid INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tmp_users (id, name, created, companyid)
VALUES 
(1, 'Lindsay', '2019-01-01', 1),
(2, 'Michael', '2019-01-02', 1),
(3, 'Stan', '2019-01-04', 3),
(4, 'Gob', '2019-01-04', 1),
(5, 'Buster', '2019-01-01', 1),
(6, 'Lucille', '2019-01-03', 2),
(7, 'Sally', '2019-01-05', 3);

-- Get users created per day, per company
SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC('DAY', created) AS created,
    companyid,
    COUNT(*) AS numberofusers
FROM tmp_users
GROUP BY 
    DATE_TRUNC('DAY', created),
    companyid
ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('DAY', created) DESC;

-- Users per company, with filter
SELECT
    companyid,
    COUNT(*) AS numberofusers
FROM tmp_users
GROUP BY 
    companyid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: @haag1 The reason I'm trying to get this done in one query is because when doing this over my real very large dataset, it's quite a heavy query. So I would prefer not to run two very heavy queries over the same dataset if I don't have to.

Comment: Well then perhaps you should gather the data into a view with an index and query on that so you aren't rebuilding the dataset

Comment: @haag1: a view is not indexed.

Comment: @dnoeth Well no, not by default but they can be indexed.

Comment: How should the result look like? You can get the company level as new rows using `grouping sets` or as new columns using `sum(count(*)) over (partition by companyid)`

Comment: @dnoeth New rows are fine, ideally if I can limit thoese extra rows to show the result of only  the "top 5" companies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grouping sets` can be used to return multiple levels of aggregation in a single Select:

```
-- Get users created per day, per company
SELECT *
FROM
 (
   SELECT
      DATE_TRUNC('DAY', created) AS created,
      companyid,
      Count(*) AS numberofusers,
      Row_Number() -- instead of TOP n
      Over (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN DATE_TRUNC('DAY', created) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
            ORDER BY Count(*) DESC) AS rn
   FROM tmp_users
   GROUP BY GROUPING SETS
    (
     (DATE_TRUNC('DAY', created), companyid)  -- daily data
     ,companyid                               -- company data
    )
 ) AS dt
WHERE created IS NOT NULL  -- all daily data
   OR rn <= 5              -- plus the TOP 5 companies
ORDER BY created ASC NULLS FIRST;
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7f09d4a86e9b6d8bdc9d5860e0616a2d)